# Problem completing proof that the Weierstrass $\wp$ function is uniformly convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, elliptic-functions

I'm having trouble following Ahlfors logic in his text concerning the proof that the $\wp$ function is convergent.

The proof comes down to whether the series 
$$\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\frac{1}{|\omega|^3}$$ is convergent.

> He states that as $\omega_2/\omega_1$ is not real, there exists a $k>0$ such that $$\left | n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2\right |\geq k(|n_1|+|n_2|)\;\; \text{for all real pairs}\;\; (n_1,n_2)$$ 
>   Then concerning ourselves with just the integers there are $4n$ pairs $(n_1,n_2)$ with $|n_1|+|n_2|=n$ giving $$\sum_{\omega\neq 0}|\omega|^{-3}\leq 4k^{-3}\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-2}<\infty$$

Is there a proof for this? Or am I missing something trivial? Also is there a typo on the sum, shouldn't it be $n^{-3}$? If someone could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its trivial. Here's a way to justify:

Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0,0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(n_1,n_2) = \frac{|n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2|}{|n_1|+|n_2|}$$ As $f(tn_1,tn_2)=f(n_1,n_2)$ for all $t \neq 0$, we can assume $n_1$, $n_2$ lie on the unit circle and restrict the domain of $f$. $f$ is continuous on a compact set so it attains its infimum, say $k$. As there are $4n$ pairs $(n_1,n_2)$ with $|n_1|+|n_2| = n$ we have $$\sum_{\omega \neq 0} \frac{1}{|\omega|^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n}{(kn)^3} = 4k^{-3} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

Comment: Wow! Just a few questions, does the $kn$ correspond to $|\omega|$? I.e. you are using the infimum so that you can bound the sum.... Also I'm not sure where the $4n$ comes from orginally, like how you can prove there are that many pairs summing to $n$. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the $4n$ even neccessary? Couldn't we just finish with the sum of $n^{-3}$ as that also converges

Comment: If we don't use the $4n$ we have a sum running over $\mathbb{Z}^2\backslash\{0,0\}$. While of course the sum still converges we can't immediately use facts about convergence of series indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The $kn$ corresponds to $\omega$ and I'm using the infimum. Writing it out explicitly, $|\omega|=|n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2| \geq k(|n_1|+|n_2|)=kn$. For the $4n$: if $n_1$, $n_2$ are positive then there are $n$ ways to sum to $n$, i.e. pairs $(n,0)$, $(n−1,1)$, $\dots$ , $(0,n)$. Since we're taking absolute values its the same for negative $n$, hence there are $4n$ pairs

Comment: i am the bosss/1111